# Installing RabbitMQ on Ubuntu 14.04 getting following error can anyone give solution?

Tags: apt, server, package-management, dpkg

I did installation like this:

1.sudo echo "deb http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian testing main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

2.wget https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc

3.sudo apt-key add rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc

4.sudo apt-get update

5.sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server

After point 5 I am getting below following error.

```
* Starting message broker rabbitmq-server                                                                                                       * FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_\{log, _err\}
                                                                                                                                         [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rabbitmq-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Sorry this is not relevant to the question. But I am curious to know as why are you still on Ubuntu 14.04 after so many good changes coming out in newer versions. Thanks!